# How to format a date store in varchar format

Tags: sql, sql-server

how can i format a date stored in varchar format.

I have saved date in varchar(255) in format dd:mm:yyyy hh:mm:ss. I need to convert or get in the format hh:mm:ss. I do not want to alter the database structure

I tried,

```
SELECT [FinishingTime] format(varchar(255), [FinishingTime], 120)
```

In addition to this question:
I would try to alter the database structure. In the Sql database if i use the datetime2(0). Then i have a problem in getting through my groovy code. I have in long i try to convert into dateformat and set in the string and later store in 
database.

```
def time1= time / 1000;   here time is in long
            def time2 = time1 + 3600 + timeLeft;  
            LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.ofEpochSecond(Finish2, 0, ZoneOffset.UTC);
            DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH);
            String formattedDate = dateTime.format(formatter);
            machine.setFinishingTime(formattedDate);    

Now i use the getter and setter in a class. 

public String getFinishingTime()
    {
        return getPropertyContainer().getString(FINISHING_TIME, "")
    }

    public void setFinishingTime(String finishingTime)
    {
        getPropertyContainer().setString(FINISHING_TIME, finishingTime)
    }
```

Now the question is if i use date time instead of string it does not write in my database or i am not able to set through setter.

Comment: What dbms are you using? I suppose MS SQL server, because of the `[]`

Comment: *Don't* save dates or times as text. That's the real problem. Strings like that can't be ordered or indexed. You can't find dates in a certain range. Use the correct types instead, eg `date` and `time`

Comment: I completely agree with the above comment.  You would be better off just forming a proper date column.  Then, you could use either convert or substring to extract the time portion by itself.

Comment: "I do not want to alter the database structure"   Yes you do.   You really do.

Comment: Another reason to not like using `varchar(255)` for storing this `FinishTime` is *do you have a good check constraint* that ensures you don't get e.g. February 30th stored in there? Or even to prevent `'It was sometime after lunch, maybe somewhere between 1 and 2. Definitely earlier than 2:30'`?

Comment: Altering your database will take some time, that is true. But your misery will end there. Keeping the column varchar will keep haunting you for ever, and will keep costing time over and over again. Its far more efficient and saves much more time to alter the database

Comment: Thank you for all your suggestions. I would try to alter the database structure. In the Sql database if i use the datetime2(0). Then i have a problem in getting through my groovy code. I have in long i try to convert into dateformat and set in the string and later store in database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a conversations just use `substring()` function :

```
select substring([FinishingTime], charindex(' ', [FinishingTime]) + 1, len([FinishingTime]))
from table t;
```

However, your idea is really bad to store date-time in custom format, it will lead you lots of trouble while data querying.

Comment: I was thinking the same, try to reformulate your idea.

Answer (score 0):

I assume it is MS SQL

```
select convert(varchar, FinishingTime, 108)
```

or

```
select convert(varchar, FinishingTime, 8)
```

Comment: [Bad habits to Kick: declaring varchar without (length)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length)